# Difference between wave vector and density matrix in numerical calculation of Schrödinger equation

Tags: python, numerics, scipy, numpy, differential-equations

I solved Schrödinger equation for a following tow-level time-dependent Hamiltonian numerically in two ways:

```
import numpy as np

def H(t):
    return np.array([[t,0.5],[0.5,-t]],dtype="complex64")
```

First, the state is treated as wave vector:

```
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
def schrodinger(t, X):
    dXdt = -1j * H(t).dot(X)
    return dXdt

T=80.
t_list = np.arange(-T, T, 2*T / 1000.0)
init_state= np.array([1.,0.],dtype="complex64")
solution = solve_ivp(fun=lambda t, X: schrodinger(t, X), t_span=[-T,T], y0=init_state, t_eval=t_list, method="RK45", vectorized=True)
```

Second, the state is treated as (vectorized) density matrix:

```
def schrodinger_rho(t, X):
    unit = np.eye(2, 2, dtype="complex64")
    dXdt = -1j * (np.kron(unit, H(t)) - np.kron(H(t).T, unit)).dot(X)
    return dXdt
T=80.
t_list = np.arange(-T, T, 2*T / 1000.0)
init_state= np.array([1.,0.,0.,0.],dtype="complex64")
solution_rho = solve_ivp(fun=lambda t, X: schrodinger_rho(t, X), t_span=[-T,T], y0=init_state, t_eval=t_list, method="RK45", vectorized=True)
```

The numerical results are as follows:

[image: wave vector]
[image: density matrix]

Here is a question : why cannot the state preserve its unitarity, say $P_0+P_1=1$, when the state is treated as wave vector? The larger the value of `T`, the stronger this tendency of violation becomes. Moreover, the numerical results become worse when I use `method="BDF"`.

I want to treat the state as wave vector because of the numerical cost. Is there any way to improve this phenomenon?

Comment: Explicit Runge Kutta methods rarely conserves integrals of motion. Did you try with an implicit Gauss Runge Kutta method?

Comment: @G. Fougeron  But isn't it true that for a smaller integration time step the integrals of motion are conserved better, even if the method is not conservative? So for a small enough time step you'll get all conservation laws that the underlying PDE has?

Comment: This is true for the short time behavior, but not necessarily for long-time behavior. For more precise info on the subject, I recommend the book by Hairer : Geometric Numerical Integration. Structure-Preserving Algorithms for Ordinary Differential Equations. If you can't find it, then maybe chackout his list of preprints http://www.unige.ch/~hairer/preprints.html

Comment: @G.Fougeron I did not try it because there is no choice of implicit Runge Kutta method in complex domain in scipy. Instead, I found ```odeintw``` where ```LSODA``` can be applied in complex domain. This method works.

Comment: Also, I do not understand why explicit Runge Kutta methods work when the state is treated as density operator. Is it related to the fact that the diagonal elements which I draw in the figure are real?

Comment: Good remark. If I understand correctly, the constant of motion you should conserve (unitarity of state) is quadratic in the coordinates of the solution vector in the first case ("state is wave vector"). Can you confirm ? What about the second case ("state is density matrix") ? Is it linear ? (please forgive my QM laymanship)

Comment: Yes, you are right. In the first case, the constant of motion is (sum of) square of absolute value of the coordinates. On the other hand, it is (sum of) the coordinates in the second case.

Comment: There you go. Then it makes perfect sense. If you check out the resources I linked, you will find proofs / explanations for this 